# htmlagilitypack getting an element's node by the name

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How can I get the node of an element by the name.  There is GetElementById, why no GetElementByName.  The element in question is:

```
   <select class="box1" name="DAY" tabindex="31"> … </select>
```

I want to be able to get this node. But I have no idea how.

Pete: please remove that this question has been answered. It is totally WRONG go try it yourself.  the node.Name is not the name of the attribute 'name' its the tagname which is NOT what I need.

Comment: Iv tried that multiple times I cant get it to work. 
var forms = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("form");  only gives me 1 descendant the <form..   how do the search the nodes inside it? the .Where returns a 0 size collection.  and document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(xe => xe.Name == "DAY"); as well 0size collection

Comment: Wrong node.Name != 'name=DAY' attribute or w,e, it is

Answer (score 2):

You are not accessing the node attribute called "name" of the "select" tags in the descendants. You are using the property Name of the tag (xe.Name). The correct approach can be :

```
document.DocumentNode.Descendants("select").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("name", "").Equals("DAY", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Watch out for nodes that don't have a name though, otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException. node.Attribute["name"].Value.Equals("DAY") could be replaced with node.GetAttributeValue("name", "") == "DAY".

Comment: I realized it some minutes ago. Thanks for pointing it out. Another thing to be careful is the string comparison, you can't guarantee the case, so it's more safe to compare with ignore case option (using string.Equals).