# How to select HTML attribute by name using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to get the value attribute in any of these input tags by targeting the name attribute using HtmlAgilityPack?

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="5" />
</form>
```

This code can get the third element in the form using `elements[2]`. But if either of the first two elements are missing, it will break. Is it possible to target the third element's `value` attribute using the `name` attribute in the HTML?

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(myHTMLFile);
var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
var elements = form.SelectNodes("//input");
var name = elements[2].Attributes["value"].Value,
```

Comment: untested: `var name = form.Descendants().Where(node => node.Name == "address");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlagilitypack getting an element's node by the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107125/htmlagilitypack-getting-an-elements-node-by-the-name)

Answer (score 0):

//input[contains(@name, 'address')]

This should work... sorry about the short answer. On mobile